# How I/O Prioritization Works (in Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, io

Something has confused me about I/O prioritization in Windows 7:

Normally, "prioritization" only makes a difference when *multiple* requests are happening for the *same* resource. However, I've noticed that when I lower my program's I/O priority, its reads *always* slows down the reads (e.g. from 60 MB/s to 10 MB/s), regardless of whether or not the disk is otherwise busy from other programs.

Why is this? Is I/O prioritization really I/O *throttling*, or does it also do something else I'm not aware of?